# Android Floating button not appearing above the video

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I need to display the floating button on the video and perform the action on it, but according to my code in preview i can see the button over the layout but while running the code button gets hidden. My code is here

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="160dp"
       android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start|left"
        >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/minimize"
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/max"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_self_avatar"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:visibility="gone"

        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_video_chat_teacher"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start|left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#a6b8c5"
         >

        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the "frame_video_chat_teacher" is added "on top" of the `RelativeLayout`

Try to put your "frame_video_chat_teacher" BEFORE the `RelativeLayout` containing your two FABs

Something like that:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_video_chat_teacher"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start|left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#a6b8c5">

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start|left">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/min"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
            android:src="@drawable/minimize" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/max"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_self_avatar"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If I do like that too my button is hidden